# How to get the last element in Pig Script

Tags: regex, apache-pig, hl7

I want to get the last element of a line using pig script. I cant use **$** as the index of last element is not fixed. I tried using Regular Expression but it is not working. I tried using **$-1** to get it but it didn't work. I am posting only a sample as my actual file contains more of PID's.

**Sample:**

```
MSH|�~\&|LAB|LAB|HEATH|HEA-HEAL|20247||OU�R01|M1738000000001|P|2.3|||ER|ER|
PID|1|YXQ120185751001|YXQ120185751001||ELJKDP@#PDUB||19790615|F||| H LGGH VW��ZHVW FKHVWHU�SD�19380|||||||4002C340778A|000009561|ELJKDP@#PDUB19790615F
```

i want ot get the last value of **PID** i;e `ELJKDP@#PDUB19790615F`
for that i have tried below code's but it is not working.

**Code 1:**

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/rt/PARSED' USING PigStorage('|'); 
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($0 matches '.*PID.*'); 
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE $2 AS id, $5 AS ame , $7 AS dob, $8 AS gender, $-1 AS rk;
```

**Code 2:**

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/rt/PARSED' USING PigStorage('|'); 
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($0 matches '.*PID.*'); 
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE $2 AS id, $5 AS ame , $7 AS dob, $8 AS gender, REGEX_EXTRACT(data,'\\s*(\\w+)$',1) AS rk;
```

**Error for Code 2:**

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed
>   to parse:   Invalid scalar projection: data : A
>   column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a
>   scalar

Please help

Comment: Your best bet is to write a UDF and pass the entire record and look for the index of the last delimiter | and get anything after that.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Can you please give an example it would be easy for me.

Comment: If it's simply a regex you can do this:  ^PID\|.*\|(.*)    that would put in the capturing group anything after the last |   for the row that starts with PID

Comment: @sniperd i used `REGEX_EXTRACT('^PID\|.*\|(.*)')` but i am getting `ERROR 1200: <line 6, column 108>  Unexpected character '|'`

Comment: That's weird.  I wonder if there needs to be some special escaping for pig?  the \ should escape the |

Comment: I have written this but getting the error mentioned above `STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/rt/PARSED' USING PigStorage('|'); 
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($0 matches '.*PID.*'); 
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE $2 AS id, $5 AS ame , $7 AS dob, $8 AS gender, REGEX_EXTRACT('^PID\|.*\|(.*)') AS rk;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(data,'([^|]+$)',1) AS rk
```

[^|]+$ matches everything to the right of the last pipe character.

[image: Output]

Comment: I tried your way i am getting `ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 3, column 102> Invalid scalar projection: data : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar`

Comment: You proably do not have enough columns in your relation since you are loading with '|' as the delimiter.Modify  MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE  REGEX_EXTRACT(data,'\\s*(\\w+)$',1) AS rk; to check if regex works.Then work on getting the other columns.Most likely for some rows you do not have $2,$5,$7,$8.That would be a separate question trying to figure out why you are getting an error.